# How to install keyboard in python virtual environement | ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I did the following for keyboard interaction;

```
pip install keyboard
```

But when I execute, I get the following error;

```
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
```

My OS is `Linux`, and I work in `python virtual environment` and use `Spyder`. In addition to `pip`, I also tried `conda install`, but none of them helped.
Some posts suggested to use `sudo`, so I tried `sudo pip install keyboard` in my python environment. But no use!!

I also tried my python script `executable` using `chmod +x`, but no success. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to run pip as root - you're supposed to run **your program** as root!

Answer (score -2):

did you tryed "sudo su"?
or is the problem that youre trying to intsall it for python3?
"sudo pip3 install keyboard"

Comment: yes I did but help.

Comment: so "sudo pip3 install keyboard" didnt work either?

Comment: yes I tried both

Comment: did you installed python-pip as root?